# Moq Verify events triggered

Tags: c#, moq

```
class A
{
    event EventHandler Event1;
}
var mock = new Mock<A>();
```

How do I verify Event1 was fired? (without using manual event handlers / triggered flags)

Comment: Any way to use Verify? I'm currently subscribing to it and changing a flag when triggered... but it's kinda messy.

Comment: Messy? Testing events the way they are supposed to work?

Comment: Never mind. I wanted some way to use Verify for the reason why I use Assert: clearer code and ease of typing.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

```
var mock = new Mock<IInterfaceWithEvent>();
mock.Raise(e => e.MyEvent += null, EventArgs.Empty);
mock.VerifyAll();
```

or if you want to make sure that act raises an event, your setup should look like:

```
mock.Setup(foo => foo.Submit()).Raises(f => f.Sent += null, EventArgs.Empty);
// ...
mock.VerifyAll();
```

Answer (score 33):

I'm not sure I really understand why you ask. If you have a `Mock<A>`, then you control the mock so why verify that it has done something that you control?

That said, although I do use Moq's raise/raises, I still often use a flag with a lambda, which I find fairly clean:

```
bool eventWasDispatched = false; // yeah, it's the default
var a = new A();
a.Event1 += () => eventWasDispatched = true;
a.DoSomethingToFireEvent();
Assert.IsTrue(eventWasDispatched);
```

Comment: This is a good answer, but keep in mind that if the event follows the standard (sender, EventArgs) pattern then you will need to adjust the lambda accordingly:
`a.Event1 += (sender, args) => eventWasDispatched = true;`

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this?

```
public class MyClass : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _name;
    public string Name
    {
        get => _name;

        set
        {
            _name = value;
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(Name)));
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
```

In your tests:

```
// This interface contains signatures which match your event delegates
public interface IPropertyChangedEventHandler
{
    void PropertyChangedHandler(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e);
}

public void WhenSettingNameNotifyPropertyChangedShouldBeTriggered()
{
    // Arrange
    var sut = new Mock<MyClass>();

    var handler = new Mock<IPropertyChangedEventHandler>();
    handler.Setup(o => o.PropertyChangedHandler(sut, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(MyClass.Name))));

    sut.PropertyChanged += handlerMock.Object.PropertyChangedHandler;

    // Act
    sut.Name = "Guy Smiley";

    // Assert
    handler.Verify();
}
```