# using moq - Unit test for void methods c#

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq, mstest

I want to write unit test for this FirstPageLoad method. This is a void method so i don't know how to write a unit tests for this void methods.

```
public class PagingSevice : IPagingService
{
    private EventHandler<PageEventArgsHelper> pageEventArgs;

    private List<string> PageGuids; 

    public void FirstPageLoad()
    {
        SetPageLoading(0);
    }

    public void SetGuids(List<string> pageGuids)
    {
        PageGuids = pageGuids;
    }


    private void SetPageLoading(int pageNumber)
    {
        if (!PageGuids.Any())
        {
            PageEventArgsHelper page = new PageEventArgsHelper(string.Empty, true, true);
            pageEventArgs?.Invoke(this, page);
            return;
        }

        bool isFirst = false;
        bool isLast = false;
        if (pageNumber == 0)
        {
            isFirst = true;
        }

        if (PageGuids.Count -1 == pageNumber)
        {
            isLast = true; 
        }

        PageEventArgsHelper pageArgs = new PageEventArgsHelper(PageGuids[pageNumber], isFirst, isLast);
        pageEventArgs?.Invoke(this, pageArgs);
    }
}
```

can i use moq.verify to test this method?

Comment: Sure. What have you tried?

Comment: @mm8: They're asking *how* to do it.

Comment: i used moq.verify. but i don't know whether it is correct or not.

Comment: Why wouldn't it be? What method that you want to verify?

Comment: @KSameera: Is there an observable side-effect from `SetPageLoading(0)`?  Does it modify anything in the object which can be seen externally?  Does it modify anything in a dependency?

Comment: FirstPageLoad  method. i need to write unit test for this method.

Comment: @David   Is there an observable side-effect from SetPageLoading(0)? -> No Does it modify anything in the object which can be seen externally? -> No. Does it modify anything in a dependency? -> No.

Comment: @KSameera: Then the only value in a test is confirming that no exception is thrown.  There's nothing to mock.  Just create an instance of the object and invoke the method.  If no exception is thrown, the test passes.

Comment: @David can you add the answer in here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on comments on the question above...

> Is there an observable side-effect from SetPageLoading(0)? -> **No**
> Does it modify anything in the object which can be seen externally? -> **No**
> Does it modify anything in a dependency? -> **No**

It sounds like the only observation that can be made about the result is "no exception is thrown".  For that you don't need to mock anything or even assert anything.  In any testing framework, an unexpected exception fails the test.  So as long as there's no exception, the test passes.  Something as simple as:

```
// arrange
var service = new PagingService();

// act
service.FirstPageLoad();

// assert
// no exception is thrown
```

Now, not knowing much about what this object does, if something were to fail in this case because there's an external dependency that isn't met, then *that* would be the externally observable side-effect.

I see no constructor or any way to inject a dependency.  So if there is one then building the unit test(s) is an opportunity to invert that dependency so it can be provided to the object.  But if there isn't one and everything happens privately within the object then the functionality is a black box and all that can be observed is the lack of an exception.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing special about a method that returns void in this context. You would just call the method and use the `Verify` method to verify that it was called as usual, e.g.:

```
var mock = new Mock<IPagingService>();
mock.Object.FirstPageLoad();
mock.Verify(x => x.FirstPageLoad(), Times.Once);
```

You may also want to verify that the [event was raised](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6378294/moq-verify-events-triggered) by the `SetPageLoading` method when you called the public `FirstPageLoad` method.

Comment: what about pageGuids list? do i need to add values to pageguids  using setguids ?

Comment: This really begs the question of the value of the test.  In this example the object isn't being tested at all.  A mock of the object is created and the test only validates that the mock exists and can be invoked.  If this test were to fail, it wouldn't be a problem with the object but instead would be a problem with the mocking framework.

Comment: @David: The answer tries to answer the actual question of how to unit test a void method.

Comment: @KSameera: `SetGuids` does add values to `PageGuids` but since the latter is private, there is no way you can test this without using reflection.